# Such pride, such strength

Tags: word, english, language

> 19th; cobra, melancholy, like, talk.
>   Reverse of 23; anger, the gathering, create.
>   Intelligent adjective; gain, gone, under reverse.
>   Never work; below, before 20, the gooseling.
>   Go figure... first. trash, huge, real, sentry.

What is his name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

His name is

> SMAUG

19th; cobra, melancholy, like, talk.

> S: 19th letter of the alphabet. Initial of Snake, Sad, Similar, Say.

Reverse of 23; anger, the gathering, create.

> M: Upside-down W (23rd letter). Initial of Madness, [Magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering), Make.

Intelligent adjective; gain, gone, under reverse.

> A: Initial of Astute, Add, Absent, Above.

Never work; below, before 20, the gooseling.

> U: Initial of Unemployed, Under, Underage(?), Ugly Duckling (though he was a swan, not a goose).
>  Perhaps "before 20" could also refer to the fact that 20 letters precede U in the alphabet.

Go figure... first. trash, huge, real.

> G: Initial of Graph (figure), Garbage, Great, Genuine.

Bonus:

> The Acrostic 1RING indicates that this character is from The Hobbit, prequel to the famous Lord of the Rings trilogy.

Comment: Very nice! The reason I used "gooseling" instead of "duckling" or "swan" was because I wanted to have the letter you needed for the next line to be in the previous line, i.e. for "S" there is "Melancholy", for "M" there is "Anger", "A" has "Under reverse", "U" has "Gooseling", although it did not wrap for the last letter- there is no "S" in the "G" description.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't notice that. You could make it wrap by adding "Sentry" (-> "Guard") to the last line ;)

Comment: Added! Great suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Partial guess

> I noticed that the first letter of each line spells "**1RING**"

Comment: Hint found!! :)